# Determine the category that an archive-page is for

Tags: categories, archives

On a *category archive page*, how do I determine what category the archive page is for? I need either the *id* or the *slug* of the category.

I am *not* looking for `get_the_category()`. This will give me all categories of the *posts* on this page (which can be subcategories of the category that the page is for). Instead, I want the category that the archive page is for. *How can I get this category?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ID of the current category will be available in the `cat` query var:

```
get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this to highlight items in my category-based navigation, and now it finally works correctly for all possible cases! Also, I just found an example that explains how to get more details about the category on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category#Print_category_data